# How to use delegation instead of NSNotification in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I'm searching for a solution, to avoid the use of NSNotifications in my code. This is an extract of my storyboard to explain my problem:
[image]

**In general there are two classes involved:**

`ScanTableView` \ `ValueCollectionView` //The Class `BluetoothManager` isn't interesting for my issue and works fine.

**ScanTableView class:**

```
import UIKit

class ScanTableView: UITableViewController
{
    @IBOutlet var ScanTableView: UITableView!

    var valueCollectionView: ValueCollectionView?

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.refreshControl!.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return BluetoothManager.bluetoothManager.peripheralArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = ScanTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("scanCell",forIndexPath: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel!.text = BluetoothManager.bluetoothManager.peripheralArray[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        BluetoothManager.bluetoothManager.connectPeripheral(indexPath.row)
    }

    func refresh()
    {
        BluetoothManager.bluetoothManager = BluetoothManager()
    }
}
```

**ValueCollectionView class:**

```
 import UIKit

    class ValueCollectionView: UICollectionViewController
    {
        @IBOutlet var ValueCollectionView: UICollectionView!

        var scanTableView: ScanTableView?

        var valueCollectionViewCell: ValueCollectionViewCell = ValueCollectionViewCell()

        override func viewDidLoad()
        {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            BluetoothManager.bluetoothManager.valueCollectionView = ValueCollectionView
            self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
            let disconnectButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Disconnect", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "disconnect:")
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = disconnectButton;
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        }

//Function to go back to the ScanTableView
//The ScanTableView should be clear after the reload
        func disconnect(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
        {
            BluetoothManager.bluetoothManager.disconnectPeripheral(BluetoothManager.bluetoothManager.selectedPeripheralIndex!)
            //Remove all Items of the TableView
            BluetoothManager.bluetoothManager.peripheralArray.removeAll()
            let switchViewController = self.navigationController?.viewControllers[1] as! ScanTableView
            self.navigationController?.popToViewController(switchViewController, animated: true)

    // This part doesn't work! The appearing TableView isn't cleared
                    scanTableView?.ScanTableView.reloadData()

        }

        override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
        {
            return BluetoothManager.bluetoothManager.measurementValue.count
        }

        override func collectionView(tableView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
        {
            let cell: ValueCollectionViewCell = collectionView?.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("valueCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ValueCollectionViewCell
            cell.ValueCollectionViewLabel.text = BluetoothManager.bluetoothManager.measurementValue[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
    }
```

**QUESTION:**

Why am I not able to reload my ScanTableView in the marked section? Nothing happens after the call:

```
scanTableView?.ScanTableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Why are you showing all that code, and what's the question? Is it merely that you don't know what delegation is and would like to know?

Comment: Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At no point in your code do you set any object as the ValueCollectionView's `scanTableView`. Thus, it is `nil`, and the `reloadData()` line has no effect.

In other words, if you want to use delegation, there has to *be* a delegate.

Comment: Okay and how can I fix that? I tried to add: "valueCollectionView?.scanTableView = ScanTableView" To my scanTableView's viewDidLoad function. But I always get errors.

Comment: The error say's: "Cannot assign a value of type 'UITableView!' to a value of type 'ScanTableView?'"

Comment: ScanTableView is a view controller type, not a table view type. The delegate needs to be the ScanTableView itself.